# compare and replace the value from a data-frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to pandas and dataframe .

Here I have a Y which is like

```
     col_name
       2000
       2000
       2300
       2664
       2300
       51200
```

Now, In this I have an array which is like

```
imp_features = [2000,2300]
```

So, Now I am trying to replace the values to 0 if the value is not from the array.

```
Y[~Y.isin(imp_features)] = 0
```

Now, Before doing this , I am trying if the value is 2664 then replace it with 2300 like this.

I tried like this

```
 y = pd.Series(np.where(y==2664, 2300,y))
```

But not working. can any one help me wit this.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Y = Y.replace(2664, 2300)
Y = Y.where(Y['col_name'].isin(imp_features), 0)
Y 

   col_name
0      2000
1      2000
2      2300
3      2300
4      2300
5         0
```